# L is a complete lattice, prove that there exists $x \in L$, which is a fixed point of $f$ and is the smallest $y$ that $f(y) \le y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, lattice-orders

I have such task:

Let $(L, \le)$ be a *complete lattice* and $f: L \to L$ a monotonic function. Proof that there exists $x \in L$ which is a fixed point of $f$ and is the smallest $y$ that $f(y) \le y$.

I believe it has much to do with the *Knaster–Tarski theorem*. I think that by proving the *Knaster–Tarski theorem* I show that there in fact exists such element. But I have problems understanding the theorem's proof. Or perhaps there's a better and easier way to prove that.

If anyone could explain that in simple words I would be very thankful.

Comment: You're entirely correct. In fact, the theorem you're looking to prove _is_ the Knaster-Tarski theorem as stated (and proved) in Davey and Priestley's _Introduction to Lattices and Order_. That said, it's currently very hard to answer your question -- you say you have problems understanding the theorem's proof, but _where_ are you having problems? Can you be more precise about what parts of the proof you do/don't understand? As for your goal, again, what have you tried? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, this *is* the Knaster-Tarski Fixed Point Theorem.

Forget about the fixed-point part for a bit. Look at the set
$$
A:=\{y\in L: f(y)\le y\}
$$
We'd like to look at the minimum of $A$, but this need not exist in a general lattice. So, we take the next best thing, namely $x:=\inf (A)=\bigwedge A$.

Fix $y\in A$. We know that $x\le y$, so $f(x)\le f(y)\le y$. This shows that $f(x)$ is a lower bound for $A$, hence that $f(x)\le x$. Applying $f$ again, $f(f(x))\le f(x)$, so $f(x)\in A$. Since $x$ is a lower bound for $A$, $x\le f(x)$. Therefore, $f(x)=x$.

We've argued that $x$ is a fixed point of $f$. Moreover, we've shown that $x=\bigwedge A\in A$, so that we actually have $x=\min(A)$, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Thank you very much, It doesn't seem that hard when you explained it.

Comment: Why do you say $x = min(A)$? You showed $x$ is the inf of the prefix points and that $x$ is a fixpoint…. oh duh because fixed points are prefix points…

Comment: @Hans I showed that $x:=\inf(A)\in A$, which shows that $A$ has a smallest element, namely $x$.